# return -1 in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, return

I was given code and I don't understand why the function **returns -1**. I feel that it is a typo. The code is given below:

```
int equilibrium(int array[], int size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int left_sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] == sum - 2 * left_sum) {
            return i;
        }
        left_sum += array[i];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who gave you the code?

Comment: wha if size =0, then none of the loop will run

Comment: It looks like the function returns an index into the array, or -1 to indicate that it couldn't find a valid index to return.

Comment: What do you think it should return instead?

Comment: This code was given to me from a previous test a year ago, and they do not have the answer. I feel like it should return the index if the array. This is my best answer I can give.

Comment: Step through it in a debugger and see why.

Comment: What is your question? Why there is a `return -1;` line in the code? Or why you get -1 when you call with a certain set of parameters?

Comment: Questions that ask for opinions are off-topic. Without a definite problem statement, answers, in the formal sense, are not possible.

Comment: Wait, the question asks why the `main` function returns `-1`, but the code you provided us with has no `main` function.

Comment: all code paths must return a value. `return i` is based on a condition, and that condition may not always be true, so `return i` may not always be reached. `return -1` is the "catch-the-rest" condition,, and will be hit if the `return i` condition is not met. `i` is an index in an array, and returning -1 indicates the condition was never met since you don't index arrays with negative values. Some people see red with functions that have multiple return paths, I don't know why, just a matter of taste I suppose. Nothing at all fundamentally wrong with multiple returns.

Comment: Just to make it explicitly clear, `return -1` is used, because `0` is a valid return option for the array index, and cannot be used to indicate an error in the function. So the function returns -1, since that can never be a valid index and would indicate an error with the function.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it uses -1 to mean "not found", it looks like a search function trying to find an index `i` where the condition in the innermost `if` is true.

Answer (score 1):

`equilibrium` returns the equilibrium point of an array as an index in the array. When the array doesn't have an equilibrium point, the function returns `-1` instead. It is used as followed:

```
int equilibrium_idx = equilibrium(somearrayvalue, somesize);

if( equilibrium_idx == -1 )
    printf("It isn't balanced\n");
else
    printf("The equilibrium index is %d\n", equilibrium_idx);
```